# What is wrong with the pan in which I make my caramels, and what kind of pan should I be using?

Tags: candy, caramel

I am an amateur caramel maker!  I have made caramels for years, but recently my caramels have started turning really hard.  I have a new pot, and I think it holds the heat for too long, as the thermometer continues to rise even after I have removed it from the heat.  This is a stainless steel pot with a thick copper bottom.  What would be the best kind of pan to use?  I am on a tight budget, so copper is out of the question.

Comment: Copper holds heat really well. If you want it to heat up and then stop heating immediately, you'll probably want a pan where the heat dissipates quickly .. which is probably like a thin aluminium pan or something, something cheap lol. But I'm not a caramel-maker-man, so I won't post an answer.

Comment: Actually, your question probably has the answer here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/46420/24248 which makes this question technically a "duplicate". Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Either take pan off the heat before the level you want so it can keep rising to around the right temperature ( what I would do for any sugar syrup) OR place the pan into iced water as soon as it's at the right temperature to take all the heat out of your pan.

I think your pan is probably ideal for sugar work as the thick base helps regulate the heat and will be more even.  The only issue is having to change your cooking style to accommodate.